# Couldn't get any response

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am Sending post request to my login but I am not getting any response.I checked my code but couldn't understant why it is not sending any response.I am using express-typescript.
This is my login controller

```
export const login = asyncErrorHandler(
  async (
    req: Request<{}, {}, LoginRequestBody>,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { phoneNumber, password } = req.body;

    if (!phoneNumber || !password) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(400, "Please enter all the details"));
    }
    console.log(req.body);

    if (!validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(400, "Please Enter correct phoneNumber"));
    }
    console.log(req.body);

    let user = await User.findOne({ phoneNumber });
    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(400, "User doesn't exists"));
    }

    if (password.length < 8) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHandler(400, "Password should consists atleast 8 charecter")
      );
    }

    const verifyPass = verifyPassword(password, user.password as string);
    if (!verifyPass) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(404, "Please enter correct credentionals"));
    }

    const data = {
      user: {
        id: user._id,
      },
    };

    const authtoken = token(data);

    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        success: true,
        authtoken,
        user,
      })
      .end();
  }
);
```

This is My LoginRequestBody

```
export interface LoginRequestBody {
  phoneNumber: string,
  password: string
}
```

This is my asyncEventHandler

```
const asyncErrorHandler = (func: ControllerType) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    return Promise.resolve(func(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
};
```

index.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";
import compression from "compression";
import helmet from "helmet";

import connect from "./connectDB";
import { authentication } from "./routes/authentication";
import { handleError } from "./middleware/errorHandling";

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());

app.use("/api/v1/users", authentication);

const server = http.createServer(app);

connect();

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server running on http://localhost/8080");
});

//middleware to handle errors
app.use(handleError);
```

authentication.ts

```
import express from "express";

import { getUser, login, signup } from "../controller/users";
import { fetchUser } from "../middleware/fetchUser";

const router = express.Router()

export const authentication = () => {
  //route - api/v1/users/signup
  router.post("/signup", signup);
  //router - api/v1/users/login
  router.post("/login", login);
  //route - api/v1/users/dynamicId
  router.get("/:id", fetchUser, getUser);

  return router
};
```

Can someBody please help me where I am wrong.

Comment: FYI, don't use the `.end()` in `res.json().end()`.  The `res.json()` already calls `.end()` itself.  And, `.status(200)` is not needed as `200` is already the default status.  So, `res.status(200).json(...).end()` can be replaced with `res.json(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `authentication` middleware, so that the handlers get mounted. Now, it just returns route handlers when accessed, which is why it hangs.

Try this:

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", authentication());
```